# atomic 'read-modify-write' in javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm developing an online store app, and using Parse as the back-end. The count of each item in my store is limited. Here is a high-level description of what my `processOrder` function does:

1. find the items users want to buy from database
2. check whether the remaining count of each item is enough
3. if step 2 succeeds, update remaining count
4. check if remaining count becomes negative, if it is, revert remaining count to the old value

Ideally, the above steps should be executed exclusively. I learned that Javascript is a single-threaded and event-based, so here are my questions:

1. no way in Javascript to put the above steps in a critical section, right?
2. assume only 3 items are left, and two users try to order 2 of them respectively. The remaining count will end up as -1 for one of the users, so remaining count needs to be reverted to 1 in this case. Imagine another user tries to order 1 item when the remaining count is -1, he will fail although he should be allowed to order. How do I solve this problem?

Following is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("processOrder", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var orderDetails = {'apple':2, 'pear':3};

    var query = new Parse.Query("Product");

    query.containedIn("name", ['apple', 'pear']);

    query.find().then(function(results) {
            // check if any dish is out of stock or not
            _.each(results, function(item) {
                    var remaining = item.get("remaining");
                    var required = orderDetails[item.get("name")];

                    if (remaining < required)
                            return Parse.Promise.error(name + " is out of stock");
            });

            return results;
    }).then(function(results) {
            // make sure the remaining count does not become negative   
            var promises = [];

            _.each(results, function(item) {
                    item.increment("remaining", -orderDetails[item.get("name")]);
                    var single_promise = item.save().then(function(savedItem) {
                            if (savedItem.get("remaining") < 0) {
                                    savedItem.increment("remaining", orderDetails[savedItem.get("name")]);
                                    return savedItem.save().then(function(revertedItem) {
                                            return Parse.Promise.error(savedItem.get("name") + " is out of stock");
                                    }, function(error){
                                            return Parse.Promise.error("Failed to revert order");
                                    });     
                            }
                    }, function(error) {
                            return Parse.Promise.error("Failed to update database");
                    });
                    promises.push(single_promise);
            });
            return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

    }).then(function() {
            // order placed successfully
            response.success();

    }, function(error) {
            response.error(error);
    });
```

});

Comment: Think about it, this has nothing to do with JavaScript's processing model. It has everything to do with the processing model and transactional safety of the parse.com infrastructure. Your "two users buying two each" is functionally equivalent to "four users buying one each from four different endpoints." Or "17 users trying to buy 7 each from 17 different endpoints." So, look to parse.com's documentation on transactional safety.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If javascript has mutex, then I don't need to worry about this issue. As far as I know, parse does not provide any mechanism to guarantee this type of transnational safety

Comment: Again: It has nothing to do with JavaScript, you're looking at the wrong level. No mutex in the world on *one* browser could control what happens on *another*. It's a matter of how and whether parse.com's infrastructure provides a means of handling this. *That's* where you need to look, not at the language.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my understanding is that since this code runs on cloud, mutex would help. So when multiple users try to run this code, only one of them will be allowed to r-w-m the database

Answer (score 0):

> no way in Javascript to put the above steps in a critical section, right?

See, here is the amazing part. In JavaScript *everything runs in a critical section*. There is no preemption and multiprocessing is cooperative. If your code started running there is simply no way any other code can run before yours completes.

That is, unless your code is done executing.

The problem is, you're doing IO, and IO in JavaScript yields back to the event loop before actually happening kind of like in blocking code. So when you create and run a query you don't actually continue running right away (that's what your callback/promise code is about).

> Ideally, the above steps should be executed exclusively.

Sadly that's not a JavaScript problem, that's a host environment problem in this case Parse. This is because you have to explicitly yield control to the other code when you use their APIs (through callbacks and promises) and it is up to them to solve it.

Lucky for you, [parse has atomic counters](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/increment-operators/). From the API docs:

> To help with storing counter-type data, Parse provides methods that atomically increment (or decrement) any number field. So, the same update can be rewritten as.

```
gameScore.increment("score");
gameScore.save();
```

There are also atomic array operations which you can use here. Since you can do step 3 atomically, you can guarantee that the counter represents the actual inventory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I'm new to JavaScript, it's good to know everything runs in a critical section except IO! I'm already using atomic counters, so I know step 3 is run atomically. But my question is that when the inventory becomes negative, it does not necessarily mean other people really cannot order (see the example I gave above)